# wp_login hook does not send post request to different domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I have hook in `wp_login` in my WordPress site. It contains ***working*** code which sends a POST request to a different domain. This code has been tested on a different php server, and with Postman app.

I have tried to use *Code Snippet* plugin, and I have tried to use it directly in *functions.php* file. No luck in both cases.

Also, I know that it is executed, because if I paste there some invalid code, I will get an exception (inside the function).

The thing is that hook in WordPress does not send POST request. So, I am wondering if WordPress has some settings disallowing it to send requests to different domains?

Here is the code I tried in *Code Snippet* and in *functions.php*:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'notifyERP5' ) ) {
function notifyERP5($user_login, $user) {
        $Session = 'test session id';
        $url = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/users/setup';
      
        $Id = $user->ID;
    $data = array(  "session" => $Session,
            "username" => $user_login,
            "user_id" => $Id);

        $query = json_encode($data);
        $ch    = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    
   }
add_action('wp_login', 'notifyERP5', 10, 2);
}
```

Again: this function was tested in different php server, and with Postman app from different machine, and it works.

Can you give me a hint where to look? Why this hook doesn't work at `wp_login`?

Comment: Is the whole code working in WordPress on the first server? Or is it only not working on the `wp_login` hook?

Comment: @Shoelaced This code works in other php server, which is not wordpress. I have only two suspects: 1) Is it only once we can assign the hook? Maybe there is another hook for wp_login... 2) Is there a sitting in wordpress disallowing rest calls to different domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given configuration of POST request, it will not pass thru if target machine has no SSL certificate, or has a development SSL certificate. Moreover, it has been tested without SSL, and still no luck.

**Conclusion**: Target machine has to have valid SSL certificate.